# Как отменить стиль линии у Paint?

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
p.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 20, 10, 5, 10}, 0))
canvas.drawLine(crX, crY, ceX, ceY, p);
```

Как теперь отменить этот стиль, чтобы нарисовать простой сплошной линией?

Comment: Что насчет `p.setPathEffect(null);`?

Comment: В документации вполне уверенно заявлено , что передача `null` вместо PathEffect отменяет примененный эффект. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setPathEffect(android.graphics.PathEffect)

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отмены установленного эффекта нужно вызвать метод `setPathEffect`, передав ему `null`:

```
p.setPathEffect(null);
```

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setPathEffect(android.graphics.PathEffect)) по этому поводу.